# Install vim in node Docker image

Tags: vim, docker

I'm trying to install vim in my image. I'm using `node` as base image:

```
FROM node

RUN apt-get update & apt-get install vim

//more things...
```

I get this error:

> E: Unable to locate package vim

Comment: Is there a typo `&` and `&&` aren't the same! Have you tried `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install vim`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are only using a single ampersand (`&`) in your `RUN` directive, which runs a command in the background in bash. Change it to include two ampersands (`&&`). Please also notice the `-y` *(automatic yes to prompts)* I have added to the `apt-get` statement, without which your `docker build` command will fail:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim
```